# Pass array of string from ajax to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I need to send an array of string from ajax to a controller and I need to return a file to download. I already look and everywhere says that the same solution, but I can not make it work. I have put a break on the controller, but never entered.
**The controllers are in different project.**

```
SOLUTION
    PROJECT 1
        Controllers
            ApiControllers
            RenderMvcControllers
            SurfaceControllers
                ExportController
    PROJECT 2


function GetData() {

var stringArray = new Array();
stringArray[0] = "item1";
stringArray[1] = "item2";
stringArray[2] = "item3";
var postData = { values: stringArray };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/umbraco/Surface/Export/HandleDownloadFile",
    data: postData,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert();
        alert(data.Result);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error: " + data.responseText);
    },
});
}

class ExportController : SurfaceController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HandleDownloadFile(string[] productList)
    {
        return CurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have specified `contetType: 'json'`, therefore you must stringify the data `data: JSON.stringify(postData),` but your method needs to be `public ActionResult HandleDownloadFile(string[] values)` (or use `var postData = { productList: stringArray };`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are sending array values via AJAX, you'll need to ensure that the `traditional` attribute is set to true (which allows this behavior) and that your parameter is named to match what MVC expects that it should be `productList` :

```
// This is important for passing arrays
traditional: true,
```

Secondly, since you are posting this to a different project, you may need to explicitly define where the project is running by using an absolute URL (as a relative one would be used by default and would likely point to your current project) :

```
url: "{your-other-project-url}/umbraco/Surface/Export/HandleDownloadFile",
```

Finally, you may want to try removing the `contentType` attribute as that is used to define what the server expects to receive in it's response. Since you aren't expecting JSON back (and instead are expecting a file), you could consider removing it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // Consider making the URL absolute (as it will be relative by default)
    url: "/umbraco/Surface/Export/HandleDownloadFile",
    // This is important for passing arrays
    traditional: true,
    // Make sure that productList is used as it matches what your Controller expects
    data: { productList: stringArray }.
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.Result);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error: " + data.responseText);
    },
});
```